# HTML: Browser opens 2 tabs when someone clicks a link on my web site?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div onclick="window.open('http://example.com')" >
<p>1234 Main St, New York, NY</p>
<p>Price: $200,000/p>
<p>4 Beds / 3 Baths</p>
<p>2000 sqft</p>
<a href="http://example.com">More Info</a>
</div>
```

If the person hovers over the part of the DIV that is not the hyperlink, it only opens one window.

If the person clicks on the hyperlink within the DIV, it opens 2 windows (one for the DIV and one for the hyperlink).

Is there any way around this 2x opening window scenario?

Comment: Why the onclick? Won't the link suffice?

Comment: This behavior is expected as you have a `window.open` command for the parent `div`. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Hal, it's for a very detailed real estate listing. I don't want all of the text (bed/bath/price/sqft) to be a hyperlink. I only want the "More Info" to be viewed as a blue hyper link. But what I do want to do is make the whole listing clickable to view More Info even if they don't click the hyperlink itself

Comment: Do you want the entire div to be clickable link?

Comment: Jason, any connection with Bear McCreary? Eheh (BSG OST :D)

Comment: @Wai Wong, yes. I want the entire div to be clickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution:

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="return false;">More Info</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the div clickable by making the link into a block element with css

```
div a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. this would only work if the div only has a link inside of it. Didnt check the entire code properly

Answer (score 0):

That's because the click event bubbles up. It initiates when you click the anchor element, than bubbles up to the div, and executes that too.

You need to capture the click event inside the div (using a function), and then call the event's `stopPropagation` method to stop it from bubbling up.

More info about event bubbling here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: this looks promising but how would I do that with the onclick?  Would it be .....    *onclick="if (!e) var e = window.event;e.cancelBubble = true;if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();window.open('http://example.com')"*

Comment: The code I posted in the comment directly above doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, I tried the following code and it didn't work:
*<div onclick="if (!e) var e = window.event;e.cancelBubble = true;if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();window.open('example.com')">....</div>*

Comment: @TeddyR you can put a function reference inside your onclick attribute (`onclick="myFunc"`) and use that function to stop the event. But Rob's suggestion is much easier (a bit dirtier, depending on your opinion on unobtrusive javascript, but then again, so is an onclick attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same function in both the DIV and the A HREF, and manage the opening inside that function to call the window only once, that will work.

Edit : If you care at least a little about Search Engine Optimization you should not use that caption for the link, but more something mentionning the content of the next page like "House details" or better depending of the context/look of the page.

Comment: I believe that is what Peter Kruithof is suggesting but I have not been able to get the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and please don`t laugh on my silly mistake. But two tabs was opening because i am having a link and having target='_blank' and also calling a function too on the same like:

```
<pre>
$('#foo').on('click',function(){
// some code
window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");
});
```

where also i have added the target as _blank. i removed the target attribute from the anchor and it works fine for me. Hope you are not doing same.